# I need to match ID video of a facebook video link

Tags: regex, facebook

I need to match the ID video of a facebook video link:

https://www.facebook.com/dibattista.alessandro/videos/**689793084466092**/?pnref=story

P.S.

- dibattista.alessandro is dynamic;
- https or http;
- ://www.facebook.com/ and /videos/ are static;
- /?pnref=story maybe not exist.

I'm not pratic with regular expressions.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex with positive look ahead like this:

```
\d+(?=\/\?|$)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/hT2zD0/2)**

Comment: not working with this link https://www.facebook.com/dibattista.alessandro/videos/689793084466092

Comment: Downvoter why do you consider the answer as no useful? Any comment to improve it?

Comment: @FlavioTroja thanks, fixed that. I don't know facebook links so based in OP link. Working now